# Error when adding ppa repository: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found

Tags: apt, ppa, proxy

I had to reinstall Ubuntu today and despite having configured proxy for Apt, when trying to add a new PPA, the step that communicates with `keyserver.ubuntu.com` fails:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
 Sublime Text 3 Installer: the package in this PPA downloads and installs the latest Sublime Text 3 beta builds.

For more info, see: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/sublime-text-3-ubuntu-ppa-now-available.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp_wo9o6sl/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp_wo9o6sl/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I have no trouble installing package via Apt, so as far as I can tell, proxy is setup properly:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::proxy "http://my-proxy:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://my-proxy:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://my-proxy:8080/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://my-proxy:8080/";

$ env | grep proxy
http_proxy=http://my-proxy:8080/
ftp_proxy=ftp://my-proxy:8080/
https_proxy=http://my-proxy:8080/
```

I can communicate with the `keyserver.ubuntu.com` as well:

```
$ curl keyserver.ubuntu.com

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>SKS OpenPGP Public Key Server</title>
  </head>
  ...
```

I can't remember having done anything different in the past. I only had to configure `http/s_proxy` environment variable as well as configuring `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: This isn't necessarily a duplicate of that question. My environment was setup properly and in such a way that if it wasn't for the sudo regression bug, it had to work without adding env_keep entries to sudoers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duh! In order to verify the proxy settings are setup correctly for `sudo`, I entered the interactive mode:

```
$ sudo -i
$ env | grep proxy
https_proxy=http://my-proxy:8080
```

It turned out that only `https_proxy` was set for root. As I had set the proxy env vars in `/etc/environment` this was a bit strange as `sudo` should source `/etc/environment`.

Then I stumbled upon [#1301557](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1301557). 14.04.1 being an LTS version, it is a bit disappointing that this bug hasn't been fixed even though it was reported way back in 2014-04-02.

In order to fix this problem, both of the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` should be added to `env_keep` in `sudoers`:

```
Defaults        env_keep +="http_proxy"
Defaults        env_keep +="https_proxy"
```

This fixed the problem.